# hyphen character and apostrophe character - the same ASCII code in different languages?

Tags: regex, windows, macos, internationalization, keyboard

I need to specify a regex for validation of user input that allows the user to enter a hyphen character or apostrophe character on Windows Desktop operating systems or Mac OS/X desktop operating systems.

The user may have configured for the following languages:

1. English
2. French
3. Spanish
4. Portuguese
5. Hawaiian

I wan't to understand if I use a standard ASCII regex for hyphen and apostophe (e.g. `['-]`) whether that will catch the hyphen or apostrophe keys typed by the user *in most cases*.  I appreciate my definition is quite loose as there are many different keyboard layouts, OS versions,  and language definitions (e.g. fr_FR, ca_FR).

I have checked the following resources and generally searched on google, but could not find anything in particular about saying that the ASCII code generated by a **hyphen key** or **apostrophe key** will always be ASCII code 45 and ASCII code 39 respectively.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe

---

NOTE: If you feel this question is badly worded, please add a comment to help me improve it.

Comment: I just found [this](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/dashes.html) interesting article.

Comment: All these languages are based on the latin script. Why do you think ASCII would be a problem?

Comment: @mrhobo Based on the research I have done, I'm fairly confident that hyphen=45 and apostrophe=39.  I just wanted to make sure that I haven't overlooked anything.

Comment: I've used qwerty, azerty and arabic keyboards. As far as I remember they had all the same hyphen and apostrophe but this is just personal experience. On a side note if your language supports it, you might use `\p{Pd}` to match a unicode hyphen. [Further reading](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Comment: @HamZa Thanks for the info on your experience, it is useful knowledge.  Also thanks for tip, however, I think that ```\p{Pd}``` also allows non hyphen which I wouldn't want to allow the user to enter - [link to list of characters for ```\p{Pd}```](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up a couple of things:

- *[keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout)* is what determines what value get assigned to a scancode.
- *[localization settings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization)* determine in what language you should address the user, and wether the user expects a decimal point or comma.
- *[character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)* is how a [glyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) is encoded into the bits memory and, in reverse, how to decode bits into glyphs

If you're validating user input, you shouldn't be interested in scancodes. A DVORAK layout user on a QWERTY keyboard will be pressing the Q key to input an `'`. And you shouldn't mess with that. So you have *no business* dealing with keyboard layouts.

[image: blank key happy hacking keyboard]

The existence of this keyboard, should remind you, that what keys do is not your head-ache, but up to the user.

The localization settings *will* matter to you, but *not* for your regex. They will, however, tell you in what language you should put your error message, in case the user input is invalid. A good [coding practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization#Coding_practice) is to use a library like gettext to manage this.

What matters most, when you are validating input. Is just those 2 things: what is *valid* and what is the *input*.

You (or your domain expert) decide what is valid. Wether a hyphen-minus is just as acceptable as a hyphen or n-dash.

The input will be in encoded; computers work with bits, not strings of glyphs. It could be ASCII, but I'd steer towards unicode if I could help it.

As for your real concern, if I may rephrase it: "Can all users easily enter `'` and `-`?". I guess they probably can. Many important programming languages use those glyphs to resp. denote strings and as a subtraction operator. And if your application needs to (dis)allow certain glyphs you can [put unicode code points or categories in your regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html).